# How does golang plugin verify version of packages?

Tags: go, plugins

I'm trying to use golang plugin and always get runtime error when calling `plugin.Open`.

`plugin.Open: plugin was built with a different version of package`

I'm sure the plugin was build with same code. Now I'm totally confused by the error message.

How does these verify mechanism work ?

Comment: The linker sees an abi change. The modules are compared via a hash, so you only get to know that they don't match, but something was different between the two builds.

Comment: Also make sure you use the latest Go 1.9.2 for both compiling your plugin and your main app. In previous versions there was a bug (see [go/issues/20248](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20248) for details).

Comment: @icza I've already updated my compiler version up to 1.9.2 and recompiled all code. Errors were still there...

Comment: @Artish Then maybe you could post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`src/runtime/plugin.go`:

```
for _, pkghash := range md.pkghashes {
    if pkghash.linktimehash != *pkghash.runtimehash {
        md.bad = true
        return "", nil, "plugin was built with a different version of package " + pkghash.modulename
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @peterSO . Can you describe how to calculate `linktimehash`&`runtimehash`?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, these hashes are computed here: https://golang.org/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/lib.go?h=genhash#L807
It seems it reads the binary output of the package, so anything can account into it which has any affect to the binary code.

Comment: Hi there, it is important to add additional information that may be contained in the link. As linked answers do break over time. Thanks